# Suppress display of zero value Integers in Table in Vaadin

Tags: java, vaadin

As is common in financial tables, I want to suppress the display of "0" for zero Integers in my Vaadin Table. Other numbers become more obvious if the zero values are presented in various other ways:

- Empty String
- [EN DASH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash#En_dash)
- [EM DASH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash#Em_dash)

Answer (score 3):

You might use either of two ways to suppress the display of zero values. The first is handy if you have many tables and/or many columns of a certain data type where you want this behavior. The second is for use on specific individual columns.

## Override `formatPropertyValue`

You can override the [`formatPropertyValue`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Table.html#formatPropertyValue(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object,%20com.vaadin.data.Property)) method in your own subclass of Table. This method is called during the display of each table cell. By testing for the case of an Integer object you can override the string being generated for presentation to the user.

This approach should work in Vaadin versions 3.1 through 7.x.

This approach affects *all the columns* in the Table of that target data type.

```
// A subclass of Vaadin Table to override formatting of Integer zero values.
public class NonZeroTable extends Table
{
    @Override
    protected String formatPropertyValue ( Object rowId , Object colId , Property property )
    {
        // Suppress display of zero-value Integers.
        // If the Property is of type Integer with a Value of zero, handle it here.
        // For other Property or Value, fallback to the default handling in the Table.
        if ( property.getType() == Integer.class ) {
            if ( property.getValue().equals( 0 ) ) {
                return ""; // Return empty string, to suppress display of zero.
                // return "\u2013";  // EN DASH
                // return "\u2014";  // EM DASH
            } 
        }
        return super.formatPropertyValue( rowId , colId , property );
    }
}
```

Thanks to the [Book of Vaadin](https://www.vaadin.com/book) collection of [Vaadin 7 example code](http://demo.vaadin.com/book-examples-vaadin7/book) for providing this information.

## Specify Converter For Each Column

Alternatively, you may want to control the formatting for *specific columns*. If so, provide a [Converter](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/data/util/converter/Converter.html) for the column, as described on the [Vaadin Wiki](https://vaadin.com/wiki) page [Formatting Data In Table](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Formatting+data+in+Table).

Converters are [discussed here](https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/datamodel.properties.html) in the [Book of Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/book).

Comment: Converters is the recommended way in Vaadin 7.

Comment: @HenriKerola Can your cite some documentation or further discussion about that recommendation? Having looked at the source code for 7.3, I see the `formatPropertyValue` method simply calling on installed or default converters. So if, as in my case, you have many tables with many columns where you want this behavior then subclassing Table to override that method seems appropriate.